# How do I make a column in a report wrap and/or break in multi-column report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where I've specified the Columns property to 3.

I want the data I have from a single query to spread across these columns.

When I print the report however, I just get a single column that spans across multiple pages till the rows run out of data.

How do I tell rs that I want the data to wrap into the next two columns?

UPDATE:  Ok, found a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159107%28SQL.100%29.aspx) on technet to give me a better explanation of multicolumns (e.g. newsletter style):

> Multicolumn, newsletter-style reports
>   display report data down multiple
>   adjacent columns. A newsletter-style
>   layout applies to the entire report.
>   When you define more than one column
>   in a report, Report Designer
>   calculates the width of the columns in
>   the report, the width of the report,
>   and the width of the space between
>   columns based on the number of
>   columns. It then displays a reduced
>   design surface so that you can place
>   report items on the report that will
>   fit within the column. Note that the
>   layout of the entire report must be
>   placed on the reduced design surface.
>   Additional columns are displayed so
>   that you can verify that the number of
>   columns you defined will fit the page
>   size dimension. You can adjust page
>   size, padding, and margins to fit more
>   columns on the page.
>
> Only PDF and Image renderers support
>   newsletter-style reports.

I still haven't quite figured out how to make the column wrap...but I'll look into it further on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed my issue by:

1. Putting 3 Tablix in my SubReport
2. Adding a Count Aggregate in my SQL results
3. Doing % calculations in the Tablix filters

For example, Tablix one has a filter formula like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!MaxRowNumber.Value <= 10, 10, Fields!MaxRowNumber.Value * .4)
```

So, if only ten rows are returned, display those ten rows in column 1.  If more than ten rows appear, then put 40% of the results in Tablix 1.

I do similar calculations for Tablix 2 and 3 to display the 30% in each Tablix respectively.

Feels like a bit of a hack...but it works.

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but the rows on the right crept up so they were appearing above the corresponding rows in the left column. (SSRS2008 R2, if relevant)

Comment: @SarekOfVulcan Have a look at the following article, it explains more in detail how to achieve wrapping columns without using that PDF-only setting: [Creating Multiple-Column Reports](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2012/11/01/creating-multiple-column-reports/)

Answer (score 0):

So one approach is to use multiple tablix with a filter that checks RowNumber and accordingly displays particular records in each table.

The other way is called **Newsletter-style report** [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms159107(v=sql.105)). This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image. It can be previewed only when you select 'Print Layout' on the Preview tab in Visual Studio. Here is an example:

1. Create a new report with the foll. dataset: `SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLENAME`
2. Add a new table to the report and select the ID and Name as columns
3. Click on the tablix and press F4 to edit the tablix properties. In the properties window, change the Size - set the width to 2in
4. Click on the report area outside the report page boundary and press F4 to edit the report properties. In the properties window, change the Column value to 3, and column spacing value to 0.1
5. On the report scroll to the right hand side, you will notice that there are 2 new columns (so totally 3 columns on the report - because you selected 3 in step 4 above). Now click on the margin at the start of the column 2 and pull it further to the left to bring it as close to the column 1. This is only to reduce the need for huge page size.
6. Right click on the report area outside the report page boundary and select Report Properties. Change the Page Size - Set the width to 10in
7. Preview the report. Now select the 'Print Layout' tab to see the result. This formatting is retained only when  report is exported as PDF or Image.

As noted in points 5 and 6 - since the report body flows into multiple columns, you must ensure that the page size is at-least equal to -> ([Original report body  size times the number of columns] + all the column spacing values). Otherwise it will look messy.